# expandable list of columns ( sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with too many columns (over 20 columns) and I would like to make some of these columns expandable to make the navigation easy for users.

is it possible, knowing that I don't have content Query?

I'll be grateful for the help!!

Comment: Do you want to hide some columns?  Did you perhaps intend to type 'expendable' rather than 'expandable'?  You could consider making a new view with fewer columns or try renaming columns so that they have fewer characters and so take up less space.

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to keep 4 or 5 columns showing up and create a button so when a user clicks on it displays the hidden columns!

Comment: You could do that without needing Javascript: just make one view that only has the 4 or 5 columns you want, make that the default view, and make another view that has all the columns.  Then users can just switch to the view that has all the columns if they want to see that.

Comment: Already tried this, the users didn't like the process of switching from a view to another! they want all the information (all the columns) in one view! thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. But most of them Requires Custom Coding.

The Very First One is to Create Your Custom [Client-side WebPart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts)(In general This is not an easy Solution If you Haven't worked with Sharepoint Framework Development.

Another Method is to Use JSON Styling combined with several custom Views: This won't give exactly what you want but it will improve the GUI of the list(I have done this with a list with 140 Fields and People are happy with it)

If I want to solve This With the fastest/easiest Solution, I would Use PowerApps/InfoPath And create a Custom Form/App to show my Data in a way I want. In this case, you can create several tabs in the form and Put related Fields in the same tab. This makes the user experience a lot better.

[This is a good video For InfoPath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V20sZvvy6H4)

[This Post Shows how to create a Tabbed Form with PowerApp](https://wonderlaura.com/2018/01/03/powerapps-tabbed-sharepoint-form/)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, the thing is that am not allowed to use any tool other than webPart (by adding JS scripts)! it's a very restricted company site!!!